# How to unset Socks Proxy

Tags: java

I am able to set a socks proxy server by code like this:

```
    System.getProperties().setProperty("socksProxySet", "true");
    System.getProperties().setProperty("socksProxyHost", address);
    System.getProperties().setProperty("socksProxyPort", port);
```

Accordind to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html, I can unset a HTTP, HTTPS and FTP proxy like this:

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", null);
```

Question: Can I unset a socks proxy as well?

By doing:

```
    System.getProperties().setProperty("socksProxyHost", null);
```

I got nothing but a NullPointerException...

Ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
System.clearProperty("http.proxySet");
System.clearProperty("http.proxyHost");
System.clearProperty("http.proxyPort");
```

this will clear the proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clear `socksProxyPort` as well.

`socksProxySet` is imaginary and does nothing; ditto `httpProxySet`, `http.proxySet`, `https.proxySet`, etc. notwithstanding what it says in several books.

However you should really be using `java.net.Proxy` for this kind of thing if you have to use and then not use a proxy.

Comment: Yes, I realize that Proxy class is a much better approach, however, I am using extended pieces of codes that didn't implement it, and it would be unpractical to change it now. I am clearing the port as well. Any other idea?